# How to know setting button click when use TWTweetComposeViewController in iOS5 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

I use these code to show twitter dialog in iOS5 simulator

```
-(void)showTwitter{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweet setInitialText:self.textView.text];
    [tweet setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
            NSLog(@"OK");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"CANCEL");
            //How to know setting button click to redirect to setting menu
            //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]]; 
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];

    [self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
}
```

The default AlertView of twitter appear:

[image]

The problem is that when I click on Settings or Cancel button, it always go to "CANCEL".
I need to catch setting button to redirect to setting menu. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult`, there are only 2 answers :

- `TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled`
- `TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone`

Thus, it is not possible to know that user chooses Settings or not. In fact, If user chooses Settings, Settings App should launch in default behavior.

Even better,  you should check whether user is configured Twitter account correctly by `canSendTweet` method. If the method returns `NO`, you shouldn't present the `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I test in iOS6 simulator and it's redirect OK. I don't have iOS5 device to test. Don't know it can redirect or not.

Comment: You can use simulator to test this feature.

Comment: iOS5 simulator not redirect, same action as click to Cancel